# PHP Fopen issues while running script same script on server and command line

Tags: php

I have one small script which open and append csv and put some information.
file name based on today's date.
But problem is coming when i run script from server it created under apache user and when same script run as cron run as different user. This creates issues and giving me errors

permission denial.

my sample code

```
$handler = fopen($file, 'a+');
fwrite($handler, date('Y-md H:i:s') . "\n");
fclose($handler);
```

Comment: I take it you ahve a lot more going on than simplyw riting the date to the file..  Right?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a filepermission issue.

Try to run the with the same user, or set the right permissions to the file, folder containing.

Comment: He said the error occured when both user/cron access it..  Sounds more like a lock issue..   As the example code only writes the date.. the few miliseconds it takes is almost a none issue...  ?